# Using a depth map

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have had issues finding any information on how to use a depth map/image to gain the distance to an obstacle.

**TLDR: I have a depth map as an OpenCV Mat, I know it's CV_16UC1, but I dont know how to get the distances from it.**

I have an Intel Realsense D415 camera, I have installed the SDK, the ROS wrapper, I have a topic with a depth map published. (/camera/depth/image_rect_raw)

Next, I've written a little program in C++ that converts the image using cv_bridge to an OpenCV image and I display it in a window, so I know it's working. (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eSC4.png )

Now I need to get the distance from it, which I have no idea how to do and have been unsuccessful in finding help for.
I imagine I'm only going to want to use the top half or 2/3 of the image, because of the way the camera will be mounted, so the bottom third/half will only contain of floor/ground.

I feel like I am missing something big and simple in order to make this work, but I literally dont even know what to do now.

Comment: I depth map usually stores the depth (= distance) for each pixel from the viewpoint (camera). In order to get the distance, you simply have to read a single depth value (RGB) for a given pixel.

Comment: See this example: [rs-pointcloud.cpp](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/examples/pointcloud/rs-pointcloud.cpp). If you want to know how compute the pointcloud from the depth map, have a look at: [pointcloud.cpp](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/src/proc/pointcloud.cpp).

Comment: The issue I've had was that I do not have access to the camera API (=librealsense2), I only got the image feed. Turns out I really just could get value of pixel (x,y) and  get the distance in mm. I just had to know it was an u_int16_t matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a depth map and you want to generate 3D points from it, you can use [reprojectImageTo3D()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1bc1152bd57d63bc524204f21fde6e02) function of OpenCV.

Before that, you need to have the disparity-to-depth mapping matrix, which can be obtained using [stereoRectify()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6) function.